# Why is there not a section describing a schema in the monaco editor JSON editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I can't find any docs for the Monaco Editor JSON language schema.  I would expect it to be here https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.json.html, but I can't find it.

Where is it?

Thanks.

I looked here:  https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.json.html

I also found https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html.  Is this the document for monaco editor JSON language?

Comment: There is https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html.  Is this what we are to use for creating custom monaco editor json schemas?  Aren't there differences between this document and what the editor understands?

Comment: Just bringing up the original question to see if anyone know the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this one too, until I found out that they follow standard JSON schema guidelines that you can find here: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#name-vocabularies-for-semantic-c